# trouble with box model

Tags: css

I can't figure out how to set up the box model for my layout.

The "[container|x]" elements you see are placeholders, which are later replaced by php.

Here is a sketch of how it should look like:

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/21j3vkl/5]

I tried to google it and search here on stack overflow and of course I did find a lot about box models and problems with it, but nothing helped me here.

This is what I already have:

html:

```
<div class='headerimage'>
[container|1]
</div>


<div class='mainwrapper'>

<div class='femininHead'>
[container|2]
</div>

<div class='lineH1'> </div>


<div class='feminin'> 

<div class='femininSub1'>
[container|3]
</div>

<div class='lineV1'> </div>

<div class='femininSub2'>
[container|4]
</div>

<div class='lineV2'> </div>

<div class='femininSub3'>
[container|5]
</div>

</div>

<div style='clear:both;'></div>


<div class='maskulinHead'>
[container|6]
</div>

<div class='lineH2'> </div>






<div='maskulin'> 

<div class='maskulinSub1'>
[container|7]
</div>


<div class='lineV3'> </div>

<div class='shopButton'>
[container|8]
</div>

</div>

<div style='clear:both;'></div>

<div class='unisexHead'>
[container|9]
</div>


<div class='lineH3'> </div>


<div class='unisex'>


<div class='unisexSub1'>
[container|10]
</div>

<div class='lineV4'> </div>

<div class='unisexSub2'>
[container|11]
</div>

<div class='lineV5'> </div>


<div class='unisexSub3'>
[container|12]
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.headerimage {
position:absolute;
left:0px;right:0px;
background-color:#000000;
height:367px;
}

.mainwrapper{
position:relative;
top:367px;
}

.femininHead {
position:relative;
width:800px;
height:87px;
top:50px;

}

.femininHead .image1_headline{
line-height:30px;
font-size:24px;
position:relative;
}

.feminin {
position:relative;
}

.lineH1{
background-image:url(/img/tempdyn/streifenlinie_horizontal.png);
width:800px;
height:1px;
background-color:#000000;
position:relative;
bottom:2px;
}


.femininSub1 {
position:relative;
width:266px;
height:125px;

float:left;
}

.lineV1{
background-image:url(/img/tempdyn/streifenlinie_vertikal.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-position:right top;
float:left;
height:128px;
width:1px;
background-color:#000000;
position:relative;
}

.femininSub2 {
position:relative;
width:266px;
height:125px;

float:left;
}

.lineV2{
background-image:url(/img/tempdyn/streifenlinie_vertikal.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-position:right top;
float:left;
height:128px;
width:1px;
background-color:#000000;
position:relative;
}

.femininSub3{
width:266px;
height:125px;
position:relative;

float:left;
position:relative;
}

.maskulinHead {
position:relative;
width:800px;
height:87px;

top:127px;
}

.maskulinHead .image2_headline{
line-height:36px;
font-size:36px;
right:300px;

}

.lineH2{
background-image:url(/img/tempdyn/streifenlinie_horizontal.png);
width:800px;
height:1px;
background-color:#000000;
position:relative;
top:133px;
}


.maskulin {
position:relative;
}

.maskulinSub1 {
position:relative;
width:266px;
height:125px;

float:left;
position:relative;
}

.lineV3{
background-image:url(/img/tempdyn/streifenlinie_vertikal.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-position:right top;
float:left;
position:relative;
height:128px;
width:1px;
}

.shopButton {
width:536px;
height:218px;
float:left;

position:relative;
}

.unisexHead{
width:259px;
height:125px;
position:relative;
line-height:36px;
font-size:36px;

}

.unisexHead .image3_headline{
line-height:36px;
font-size:36px;
}

.lineH3{
background-image:url(/img/tempdyn/streifenlinie_horizontal.png);
width:800px;
height:1px;
background-color:#000000;
position:relative;
top:594px;
}


.unisex {
position:relative;
}

.unisexSub1
position:relative;
width:266px;
height:125px;
float:left;

}

.lineV4{
background-image:url(/img/tempdyn/streifenlinie_vertikal.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-position:right top;
float:left;
background-color:#000000;
position:relative;
height:128px;
width:1px;
}

.unisexSub2 {
position:relative;
width:266px;
height:125px;

float:left;

}

.lineV5{
background-image:url(/img/tempdyn/streifenlinie_vertikal.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-position:right top;
float:left;
background-color:#000000;
position:relative;
height:128px;
width:1px;
}

.unisexSub3{
width:266px;
height:125px;
position:relative;

float:left;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the width of box 2 fixed?

Comment: yes, box2 is:

.femininHead {
position:relative;
width:800px;
height:87px;
top:50px;
}

Comment: Gotcha.  I can see your code, but I wanted to understand the broader objectives.  Sometimes a "not yet working" solution may not be a perfect representation of intent.

Comment: The term "box model" refers to how CSS formats content using inline and block level boxes.  I think what you are actually referring to is a "grid", as in graphic design and layout.  Your design is fairly straight forward and would not be all that hard to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't see why box-model can help you with this. maybe you are looking for [FlexBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)! Or go classic and use `display:inline-block` for the nested boxes(3,4,5,7,8,10,11,12) and all others just row divs.

But don't use floats any more!

Comment: I'm looking for a css 2 solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [simplified solution on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ometek/1/).

The basic idea is to wrap all the items except the 1st box in a containing wrapper `.wrap`.  A horizontal margin of `auto` along with a fixed width will center it in the page.  Within that, you have your side-by-side boxes float left and give them fixed widths.  The div below them needs to clear the `float`.

Hope the example is helpful.